Prisma method call return type of failed SELECT
I am writing my own auth service with node & ts when I came up with a question I cannot seem to find the answer to anywhere online: When a prisma method call such as .findUnique() or .update() cannot find a row that satisfies the where condition, what does the method call return?
export const readByUser_id = async (
    user_id: number
): Promise<RefreshToken> => {
    const readRefreshToken = await prisma.refreshToken.findUnique({
        where: {
            user_id: user_id
        },
    });

    if(!readRefreshToken) throw Error('User of user_id: '+user_id+' was not found.');

    return readRefreshToken;
};

I assume the return type is a falsey value such as undefined or null, and since I only check for those there is no unexpected behavior. Honestly I did not run into any errors but I wanted to know the specific type as to avoid bugs.

export const readByUser_id = async (     user_id: number ): Promise<RefreshToken | null> => {     const readRefreshToken = await prisma.refreshToken.findUnique({ ... something like this
